# HTML frame scraping using Python

Tags: python, html, frameset

We're trying to access an HTML page and get its content using Python. When it boils down to frame loading we face some problems. The code is:

```
URL = "http://192.168.1.48/_pnt_log.html"
    username = "11111"
    password ="1"

    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
    try:
        opener.open('http://192.168.1.48/_top.html', login_data)
        resp = opener.open('http://192.168.1.48/_dept.html?dn=1')
```

The HTML received is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
 <title>Remote UI<Additional Functions>:  : imageRUNNER2520</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="175,*" bordercolor="white" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
 <frame src="index06_02.html" name="Menu" scrolling="AUTO" noresize>
 <frame src="dept.html?dn=1" name="body" noresize>
 <noframes>
  <body bgcolor="white">
  </body>
 </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I want the content on `dept.html?dn=1` which is not loaded with this request. Is there any way to get the content like a broswer does?

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly the "problem" was on the how canon printer page keep the cookies and how open-close the sessions with urllib2.

I solved the problem used selenium python lib.
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

With selenium i take the html from browser and slide over the permisions problem because i work on the same session through the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

##OPEN BROSWER##
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
##LOGIN##
driver.get("http://192.168.1.48/_top.html")
driver.find_element_by_name('user_name').send_keys("11111")
driver.find_element_by_name('pwd').send_keys("1")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/p[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[3]/a/img").click()
driver.get("http://192.168.1.48/dept.html?dn=1")
##GET HTML##
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")

##SAVE HTML##
f = open('/home/itsoum/PrinterProject/html_source_code.html', 'w')
f.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()

driver.quit()
```